# Android Data Security on SD Card

Tags: android, security, android-sdcard, mdm

I have read the various question but couldn't get mine answered so I am starting this thread.

I have a requirement where in I'll get some secure data on SD cards. The app users will just plug in the shipped SD card and they should be able to access the content.

But we need to maintain the Digital Rights i.e. the data on the SD card should be only accessible to my application. No other application should be able to read this. Also, once the user license expires, the data will be wiped off.

Just wanted to add. We will be providing the device along with the application. So, we have control over the hardware.

So my questions are:

1. How to keep encrypted data[videos, text files, pdfs etc.] on SD card
2. How to restrict any other application to access this data
3. If the user breaks the root of the device, can I delete the
   application and the data on the SD card?
4. Can any MDM help? I am open to suggestion. Are there any opensource
   MDMs available?

Comment: you should store data in application storage to restrict access for other application.

Comment: 1) Just encrypt it with a key only your app knows (ideally use a different key per install). 2) You can't, although if it's encrypted no other app can make sense of it. 3) No. The user could always plug the SD card into another device or PC card reader and copy it.

Comment: The problem is my data size is huge and hence I cannot make it part of the application.

Comment: @NigelK: I think you should put it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in this area, but in my view:

- 1) Just encrypt it with a key only your app knows (ideally use a different key per install).
- 2) You can't, although if it's encrypted no other app can make sense of it.
- 3) No. The user could always plug the SD card into another device or PC card reader and copy it.

Victor - thank you (and the others) for the endorsement of my comment, hence this answer...